# How to set min and max data for child elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hello I can't set min and maximum value from database.

Actually I want to make dynamic it through PHP. In the back-end there should be two fields first minimum and second one with maximum. In maximum field, I can set maximum and in minimum field I can set, and call it through PHP in my coding.

Is that something can we do? here's coding.

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
</head>

<?php

  echo '
    <script>
    $(document).on("change", ".qty1", function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $(".qty1").each(function(){
            sum += +$(this).val();
        });
        $(".total").val(sum);
    });

    </script>';

$maxnum = 7;
if(num > $maxnum){
echo "<script>alert('Yes it is big');</script>";
}


?>
    <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
        <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
        <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
        <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
        <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
        <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
        <input type="text" class="total" value="" />
        </body></html>
```

how can I use php with jquery or should I change my coding. I don't know how I can change my coding is there any idea please?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. If it's ok with you, I'd like to offer some suggestions to improve your question. Paste the actual code here instead of referring to an external site. Include simple HTML that shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok thank you actually I am new here.
I am posting now

Comment: Hello ryantxr I updated my post.

can you help me now?

Comment: Where is the PHP code? Where are the database tables? Show how you call PHP.

Comment: Ryantxr I have added php coding. Please check it now

Answer (score 0):

you could put all values into an array and then get the min/max

```
    $(document).on("change", ".qty1", function() {
        var arr = [];
        var sum = 0;
        $(".qty1").each(function(){
                arr.push($(this).val());
                sum += +$(this).val();
        });
        $(".total").val(sum);
        $("#min").val(Math.min.apply(Math, arr));
        $("#max").val(Math.max.apply(Math, arr));

   });
```

Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w47fLjcu/